# Issues related to reliability & recoverability of Thingsboard Gateway & Thingsboard CE server Communication

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I have been trying to setup Thingsboard CE (latest) and Thingsboard Gateway. I have tried various installation methods but issue remains same.

Let me share details about the issue below:

1. I have installed Thingsboard Gateway & Thingsboard CE Server on EC2 Ubuntu (version 20.04) on two separate machines. Lets call them Machine-1 (Gateway) & Machine-2 (Server) respectively.
2. I have registered one gateway on Thingsboard server and used docker compose file generated post gateway registration to start gateway docker container on EC2 machine.

**Docker-Compose.yml for gateway**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  # ThingsBoard IoT Gateway Service Configuration
  tb-gateway:
    image: thingsboard/tb-gateway
    container_name: tb-gateway
    restart: always

    # Ports bindings - required by some connectors
    ports:
        - "5000:5000" # Comment if you don't use REST connector and change if you use another port
        # Uncomment and modify the following ports based on connector usage:
#        - "1052:1052" # BACnet connector
#        - "5026:5026" # Modbus TCP connector (Modbus Slave)
#        - "50000:50000/tcp" # Socket connector with type TCP
#        - "50000:50000/udp" # Socket connector with type UDP

    # Necessary mapping for Linux
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

    # Environment variables
    environment:
      - host=XX.XX.XXX.XXX  # Masked for security purposes only
      - port=1883
      - accessToken=TbdhVMvx1hlvXQHQlcyf

    # Volumes bind
    volumes:
      - tb-gw-config:/thingsboard_gateway/config
      - tb-gw-logs:/thingsboard_gateway/logs
      - tb-gw-extensions:/thingsboard_gateway/extensions

# Volumes declaration for configurations, extensions and configuration
volumes:
  tb-gw-config:
    name: tb-gw-config
  tb-gw-logs:
    name: tb-gw-logs
  tb-gw-extensions:
    name: tb-gw-extensions
```

3. I have opened ports suggested by Thingsboard documentation on both machines. (Let me admit even I opened all ports at some point of time to cross-out any port related issues)
4. I have started a local broker on machine-1 using following docker command
   `sudo docker run -it -p 1884:1884 thingsboard/tb-gw-mqtt-broker:latest`
   The above command runs a MQTT broker and also starts sending data on topic : **data/**
5. Here is connector information that I have configured for the gateway via Thingsboard Dashboard

**Connector Information**

```
{
  "broker": {
    "name": "Demo Broker 100",
    "host": "host.docker.internal",
    "port": 1884,
    "clientId": "ThingsBoard_gateway_100",
    "version": 5,
    "maxMessageNumberPerWorker": 10,
    "maxNumberOfWorkers": 100,
    "sendDataOnlyOnChange": false,
    "security": {
      "type": "anonymous"
    }
  },
  "mapping": [
    {
      "topicFilter": "data/",
      "converter": {
        "type": "json",
        "deviceNameJsonExpression": "Demo Device 100",
        "deviceTypeJsonExpression": "default",
        "sendDataOnlyOnChange": false,
        "timeout": 60000,
        "attributes": [
          {
            "type": "integer",
            "key": "frequency",
            "value": "${frequency}"
          },
          {
            "type": "integer",
            "key": "power",
            "value": "${power}"
          }
        ],
        "timeseries": [
          {
            "type": "integer",
            "key": "temperature",
            "value": "${temperature}"
          },
          {
            "type": "integer",
            "key": "humidity",
            "value": "${humidity}"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "connectRequests": [
    {
      "topicFilter": "sensor/connect",
      "deviceNameJsonExpression": "${SerialNumber}"
    },
    {
      "topicFilter": "sensor/+/connect",
      "deviceNameTopicExpression": "(?<=sensor/)(.*?)(?=/connect)"
    }
  ],
  "disconnectRequests": [
    {
      "topicFilter": "sensor/disconnect",
      "deviceNameJsonExpression": "${SerialNumber}"
    },
    {
      "topicFilter": "sensor/+/disconnect",
      "deviceNameTopicExpression": "(?<=sensor/)(.*?)(?=/disconnect)"
    }
  ],
  "attributeRequests": [],
  "attributeUpdates": [],
  "serverSideRpc": [],
  "logLevel": "DEBUG",
  "name": "MQTT100",
  "id": "90d4cfba-e1d0-4608-a44b-dc5c1fd1f69f"
}
```

6. As soon as I save the configuration 9/10 times device doesn't come to Sync Status. This part looks very unreliable. Sometimes it just connects but most of the times I have to struggle like enable/disable it multiple times. Often it connects when I restart my gateway container on machine-1.
7. After few restarts and enable/disable magic, sometimes it connects. I can also see data coming in continuously.
8. At this point of time if I try to check the reliability & recoverability of the system, I intentionally stop the gateway container and start it after 1 or 2 mins. 9/10 times system doesn't recover itself. No telemetry starts coming it remains stuck at last message only.
9. One more weird scenario, if I disable the connector, telemetry still keeps coming and either doesn't stop at all or stops after a long time.
10. Moreover status of the connector doesn't seems reliable to me, somehow it doesn't actually reflect the real status as in what's happening inside currently.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DKb9.png)

11. I have also tried cloud platform for Thingsboard (free trial). I am able to see same behavior.
12. **QUESTION**: Is anything that I am missing here or do you face similar issues?
13. I have also tried same with OPC-UA connector, same behavior was observed.
14. Please let me know if I need to provide any other details here. Please help.

Thanks! Your help will be much appreciated!

Trying to see reliability & recoverability of the Thingsboard IoT Gateway & Thingsboard communication. See details for further information.